# How to fix Jupyter kernal dying while using riskfolio-lib

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I recently installed riskfolio-fin and started working through some of the example notebooks on the github page. Import data, data prep all work, but as soon as I hit a piece of code requiring a call to riskfolio-fin either the kernal dies or spins for an hour.

I've checked all of the required dependencies and it looks good.

[image: Required Dependencies and Install Status]

I am trying to run the code from the following notebook- [BL Optimization](https://nbviewer.org/github/dcajasn/Riskfolio-Lib/blob/master/examples/Tutorial%203.ipynb) and constantly get hung or dead kernal on In[9] in section 2.3.

Any ideas as to why the code won't execute?

**UPDATE** I tried to replicate other example notebooks and the Hierarchical Equal Risk Contribution (HERC) Portfolio Optimization and Mean Risk Portfolio Optimization using historical estimates worked fine. Still failing on the original model listed in the note.

It looks like the root cause has to do with calls using the port.optimization(model=model, rm=rm, obj=obj, rf=rf, l=l, hist=hist) where some models seem to work but some don't. Sounds like it must be a dependency issue, but I can't figure out what it could be.

RESOLUTION - turns out to be the dependency on cvxpy. I removed and reinstalled and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

MY STEPS TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM OF RISKFOLIO-LIB:

1. pip uninstall ffn
2. jupyter notebook --generate-config
3. conda update --all